# How to do a freehand gradient

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I'm working on a project in which I need to blend a gold color into black, but the part I'm trying to use a gradient on is curved.

When I do a gradient, the bottom of this curve that I want to be black is gold, because it's right below the starting point of the gradient.

So I'm wondering if there's a way to make it so the gradient follows a path down and transitions that way rather than a linear way.

Comment: did you try using **inner glow** or other layer style like this to achieve an outline-following gradient then trimming out the unwanted gradient sections? I think this might help

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to use an angle gradient instead of a linear one.

You can do this both as a gradient overlay setting (for layer effects), and as a gradient fill setting (for vector shapes).

It will go around a center and curve, like so:

[image: Effect on layer and style window open]

Answer (score 1):

Thoose kind of gradients are easily done in Vectors using a mesh fill, so you probably can:

- Import the PSD image as a reference into Ilustrator or Corel.
- Make your mesh
- Export that and use it as a fill on your masked shape.

Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use an extremely large brush with the hardness set to zero. Then you can just "paint" your gradient any shape you want. And you can control/command select a layer to make a selection mask that matches your shape.

Comment: Hello Gregg, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your input. Could you please explain a bit bitter how you'd see such a solution applied? You can [edit] your answer to give more detail. If you have any questions about GDSE, have a look at the [help] or feel free to join us in [chat] once your reputation allows you to (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!